# Ajustar tamaño bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

alguien me ayude a que cada párrafo ocupe dependiendo su tamaño y no se adapte al tamaño de los otros ?
Quiero que los parrafos pequeños ocupen su tamaño y no bajen hasta el tamaño del mas grande.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Proyecto</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">

</head>



<body>

<div class="container">






<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: red">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.

</div>

<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: yellow">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.

</div>


<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: olive">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.

</div>


</div>






</div>











<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactamente que quieres configurar, no me queda muy claro lo que realmente quieres que haga el codigo.

Comment: Quiero que los parrafos pequeños ocupen su tamaño y no bajen hasta el tamaño del mas grande.

Comment: Puedes intentar sacarlo del `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sácalos del `div class="row"`

```css
.amarillo{
background-color: yellow;
}

.rojo{
 background-color: red;
}

.verde{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 amarillo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 rojo">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 verde">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis nulla alias hic, maxime fugiat eligendi. Nostrum, corrupti, fugit. Sed minus voluptates incidunt itaque quia error delectus doloribus laudantium neque natus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: mejor imposible..! estaba montandole el ejemplo en (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVPEMr) pero aqui quedo de lujo.

Comment: Si te sirvió recuerda marcar como correcta con la palomita :)